# Which HTTP response code should I give my application to say that authentication was successful?

Tags: ios, api, authentication

I have an API which validates a user and I don't know what to return to my iOS application when authentication is and isn't successful. I'm currently returning a 401 error for failed authentication, but how should I tell my iOS application that authentication was successful?

Comment: Probably a 200 with a token in the response. Could use 201 if it's a new user registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an HTTP 200, which indicates the request was OK without problems. You could also potentially use 201 to indicate a new session has been created.

For explanations on HTTP status codes, please see [Wikipedia's list of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Comment: I'll use 200 with a token in the response. I'll create this token in my iOS application then send it to the server. On the server I can store the token and retrieve it from the database to show that the user has successfully logged in. This seems unnecessary, though. I feel like I need to know more about API security.

Comment: It sounds like you might be doing something wrong -- you shouldn't be generating a token on the iOS device. This article should help you out: https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security/